# Inverse of positive definite matrix plus diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices

Let $C$ be a positive definite matrix, $D$ be a diagonal matrix with all elements being positive and $A=C+D$. By Woodbury matrix identity, we have $A^{-1}=C^{-1}-C^{-1}(D^{-1}+C^{-1})^{-1}C^{-1}$ or $A^{-1}=D^{-1}-D^{-1}(C^{-1}+D^{-1})^{-1}D^{-1}$. However, we have no idea about $(D^{-1}+C^{-1})^{-1}$. My question is as followings:

1. Is there is closed form of $A^{-1}$ in terms of $C$(or $C^{-1}$) and $D$(or $D^{-1}$)?
2. If no, is there a explicit relation between $A^{-1}$ and $C$ and $D$ through their eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your concept of "explicit relation"? I dont think there is one. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm dealing with an optimization problem whose objective function consisting of $D$ in terms of $A^{-1}$. The optimization variables are the elements in $D$. Here, the "explicit relation" that i expect is that i can deal with the reduced objective without $A^{-1}$ at least, and maybe the the optimization problem can therefore be solved analytically.

Comment: Then maybe you should post that problem?